# Gradle Command line Exec not working

Tags: groovy, gradle

i am creating my own plugin when i try to create a task type Exec. Its not running any command. i am getting command line error stating command is not correct. I have displayed the generated command in Exec command to command prompt and when i run it works. The code is not wroking inside gradle plugin scope.

```
task myrun (type: Exec) {
    def cp = project.files(
    project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
    project.sourceSets.main.resources,
    project.configurations.runtime
    ).getAsPath()

String myCommand = "visage -cp ${cp} visage.javafx.scene.effect.EffectTest"


println "RUN COMMAND : ${myCommand}"
workingDir project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
// classpath project.files([project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,project.sourceSets.main.resources, project.configurations.runtime,])
commandLine = [myCommand]
}
```

Can anyone tell me is there any error in the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the answer to the same [post of yours in the Gradle forum](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/command_line_exec_not_working):

`commandLine` is a list, and every argument becomes a separate element of that list:

```
commandLine "visage", "-cp", cp, "visage.javafx.scene.effect.EffectTest"
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use something like this

```
exec clause
{
executable = "bash"
args = [ "-c", """ "command arg1 arg2... argn" """]
...
}
```